# Associative Array in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, associative-array

How can I show an associative array in codeigniter view from controller page?
Here is my code below. I want to show the values of array in view.
Please help me!

```
function colorr(){
     $color['color'] = array("RED"=>"#FFCC00","GREEN"=>"#99FF00","YELLOW"=>"#FF0000");
     $this->load->view('color_all',$color);
}
```

Comment: whats the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

In your view file, you can access it by:

```
print $color["RED"]; // will output "#FFCC00"
print $color["GREEN"]; // will output "#99FF00"
```

Or you can loop:

```
foreach($color as $k => $v)
{
    print $k . " => " . $v . " <br />";
}
```

In your case, this will output something like this:

RED => #FFCC00

GREEN => #99FF00

YELLOW => #FF0000